# Installation of Wireless Printer Canon Pixma MG5450

Tags: wireless, printing, canon

How do I install my Canon Pixma MG5450.
I have downloaded the Linux drivers from Canon for the MG5450 but my Ubuntu 12.04 does not recognise them.

Comment: Please add some additional information: What drivers did you use, are you using a LAN printer or a USB printer? Also try the setup via CUPS's browser interface at http://localhost:631/

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 14.04 will help.

I connect my wireless Canon MG without installing any additional driver. Just turn on, add in 14.04, then found and done!